# long table latex with multiple row

Tags: longtable

Dear Stack overflow community, 
i try to create a long table that has multiple rows in one column, and in another column, i have one row. When i create the table with the script, but it gives me an extra line on the top of the table, and also it puts it on the next page. Can you please help to find out what the problem is?

Thanks in advance

```
\begin{longtable}  
{{
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm}% instead of "p" is "m"
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{10.5cm}|
}} 

\hline

Down-regulated(simulated-data) & 28801 15752 7608 16432 517 10097 2507 17206 15172 29142 27774 18990 
16535 10805 4087 58 22876 15101 24370 4012 11427 5084 9600 16894 19805 4293 2458 22870 2441 21254 
13253 19695 4591 10390 21017 8 29857 5596 8581 29865 4353 28352 7098 13369 18225 19201 26225 4704 
16647 9525 11714 508 29554 22186 20384 14925 11903 16565 6431 16843 136 22527 26046 26658 5968 11786 
12565 25775 20171 13040 51 17680 2400 29937 10144 23910 4889 20 23295 11705 26495 7247 11397 413 
14288 24522 6555 14376 3638 17392 20009 19615 14040 2308 5349 2565 12827 4764 24670 23303 7087 20765 
5196 29462 26289 26060 4019 29914 25948 20222 12197 21712 2686 977 14266 11573 7349 24956 25457 10579 
6568 28782 23193 23514 4880 15851 330 7595 27658 28029 5795 19654 19772 3665 29135 25879 10659 7438 
4587 29720 2763 25496 6017 25347 8356 22638 3692 8848 13179 12285 9603 28607 13295 11050 23022 21323 
17671 7894 7580 14430 18362 28794 10172 22286 25320 25651 25590 27536 9187 1584 18084 17802 15579 
1318 2006 18239 20876 13047 23182 13250 3003 18035 5206 28606 15141 14262 29614 23432 5279 23404 6239 
28438 21020 8630 2041 4933 5699 28448 2801 27316 9329 20022 5650 13377 7212 22980 2791 11173 20636 
26499 7373 3699 24165 16755 5952 14970 28729 8510 7146 8324 1976 27210 11198 11685 29773 17209 29220 
14494 11037 2514 12886 14303 3628 5961 10876 25 24479 18502 24773 21684 21947 19723 1642 4555 12036 
4622 11535 23197 25036 17138 12043 20596 13776 7220 7152 11463 4757 16767 6858 14847 22776 19439 3988 
3918 12832 289 16218 15470 12010 29466 2979 14977 1046 5864 29896 10048 22492 18143 26571 21994 20032 
12562 8396 2949 12371 11205 10140 21521 600 4998 25138 3817 8651 16957 26404 26747 1225 9021 4521 
10312 25168 20325 5381 12297 2312 5074 5305 11400 13634 3389 19753 3110 18140 15957 21430 5236 20002 
13083 10765 28374 28307 20262 8591 22046 15658 14930 1411 22251 559 25435 6213 20299 8912 15722 23493 
11266 26811 12165 28659 25876 17807 27004 27873 12888 20309 7999 8118 24990 3268 19570 19602 7134 
11712 15082 6077 13652 4284 28262 29766 29165 11630 22473 19304 22107 124 17473 25271 13082 22827 653 
27732 16449 21830 11321 25951 6694 22939 16348 4169 12286 11428 28194 1040 6753 27715 23683 8564 
20880 29661 19024 5487 20770 6540 24118 12797 15324 19848 5334 26925 18468 6943 28950 27384 24895 
6280 27813 21009 18246 13498 7294 4964 5114 19657 8343 10660 791 9984 20508 3231 3646 18376 24197 
15869 22055 14117 4476 29019 25633 109 6512 17066 6939 6437 24332 16945 7596 10585 
24402 28891 7273 29256 24135 11097 12214 12463 5805 5330 15377 16457 7464 22579 3264 8497 23226 9043 
5568 7662 8167 14474 4525 13346 15580 28848 14495 19355 11876 9715 15009 790 29146 28822 10240 5474 
2997 4643 17627 6570 14796 7832 23401 29769 2348 19953 16344 3319 8326 5665 4417 22595 22804 13716 
19331 6549 24515 15060 14807 26463 9011 11106 25947 12383 4421 24571 15261 22372 9704 3878 11886 
20355 6189 12806 26413 25412 23778 12080 10944 19591 20730 28774 9424 8712 10396 3102 22026 20349 
13859 25864 5891 11629 29538 15218 15567 18012 4013 11941 29227 23332 20187 4251 2649 12755 20729 
9829 13625 7605 2437 6498 22485 4972 10785 20630 13886 19887 15153 23611 1780 7048 22479 25096 29492 
27853 4991 25842 24478 23531 12440 3385 11419 19732 24394 17549 555 25589 6949 6463 1788 29789 21721 
19613 23329 16906 17218 15903 1997 6650 16502 22337 18361 17762 28228 9839 24652 5454 10067 12754 
3380 11926 29233 1097 1641 22119 13562 2347 15729 4428 5045 14877 1672 21121 20875 362 6152 705 28166 
18 599 95 21673 5248 5791 25769 12278 27498 14261 23673 19990 22061 24804 9825 11481 8967 23267 8061 
21614 20589 15883 25944 13128 9209 29965 23039 8585 4927 22956 27542 21291 20272 27769 25543 28291 
21408 9417 27141 4331 23933 6685 4792 27349 12979 3634 27755 11586 15510 24025 19859 10148 26963 
25450 21952 20928 28681 938 2839 27261 27429 17230 \\
Down-regulated(simulated-data) & 1290 19359 7024 13458 29054 3126 17261 10987 29308 11893 21108 10098 
12538 13819 29604 28247 26271 20549 18587 1163 26429 1702 1060 7446 26948 2420 17093 17449 9163 18482 
1774 28316 13208 7803 5684 6243 27652 13184 28530 13920 3892 20737 28934 22475 17344 27413 13075 
19865 4384 16810 12104 16381 861 23334 11223 12324 16630 2592 5428 12088 14508 22728 26779 10476 
15215 4761 5261 12113 14148 9100 14655 4580 2767 23836 26500 8385 9982 11007 18331 23912 27150 18400 
28124 20804 15840 21630 10222 27319 13911 19830 7522 22907 1130 17387 25989 10952 21821 14840 11143 
16198 18249 16605 24046 13632 22860 1844 15283 26710 11324 12407 2524 5806 2205 21277 177 7969 23189 
2078 29438 11835 1576 24695 23027 8925 11136 21321 8060 12694 12413 7162 1436 2528 6021 1677 20776 
23789 14487 15179 24662 14826 17775 21247 12110 1499 27209 18187 20195 24715 12404 20683 21968 19561 
20846 20101 26005 11278 27897 1107 16655 3499 9128 724 7301 27374 16177 3300 16900 22128 16360 23204 
4427 8112 6309 5322 8861 20070 19147 26079 8210 10727 10661 1793 12226 23635 4477 13409 19525 13400 
6078 10768 24862 21443 27865 8598 27502 21812 24418 23692 969 13596 8338 1501 658 19992 24833 13035 
2891 8532 6063 15522 16259 9017 6850 5046 9809 8640 24174 19168 19459 8539 3587 28995 17168 8817 
28038 832 13777 2804 12264 28832 19060 102 1831 16700 20434 29333 5036 21825 7752 21885 26190 22899 
12989 14058 25329 25815 26952 26249 17125 25172 10260 8399 19448 8127 3087 7775 442 8786 16529 25015 
11107 16691 26600 11664 26656 2835 9902 12017 5642 26833 29636 17847 26493 8185 19070 19541 7495 
25786 8248 10925 24857 16833 17420 7122 17958 28556 9582 26167 2050 6062 12361 15451 11645 6999 12213 
18377 25241 2779 23686 4281 20657 21109 11347 18309 28281 761 8965 738 22016 17400 24908 13605 17514 
20836 4634 4497 21029 19384 29854 5779 24613 20422 25003 27368 7078 5243 9605 14393 4725 28491 12588 
23649 16977 4108 3591 11696 16508 23562 3142 7455 10595 29372 18978 20265 6876 20985 10711 28551 
12678 4432 2717 10692 7197 26767 5697 4367 29230 7655 6696 8706 11189 19261 15090 7512 25729 23442 
21883 14470 6857 14268 22904 25366 17152 29484 6907 20957 4679 21554 26128 23837 26987 27997 14284 
7243 9291 27805 6115 26634 2031 2272 5574 15715 17867 2097 12861 18381 24802 23663 15974 12026 17352 
28472 10429 27515 10372 28033 28929 19365 1205 27149 2403 10091 283 16109 7040 2498 7480 17464 18075 
12221 799 10588 11585 13365 24511 12705 27007 18031 12215 24059 4338 3037 7161 6002 12586 25527 19042 
12959 23845 21099 20643 4612 7107 18687 3762 6814 8086 21820 11288 11230 14476 6505 3697 8092 24905 
18215 13286 20650 22213 13373 27938 13435 9837 13847 25361 7003 20609 9749 24073 27565 3454 \\
& 13577 20673 29765 11275 29243 12075 8790 16538 \\ \hline
\caption{Down-regulated detected with EdgeR}

\end{longtable}
```

Comment: it  is always better if you post a complete example document not just a fragment, bit you have spurious duplicated `{`  here `{{` this table only has two rows, so it isn't very "long" page breaking can only happen between rows, not mid-cell.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a list not a table, then page breaking can happen at the natural point mid-way through an item.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\section*{Down-regulated detected with EdgeR}
\begin{description}
\item[Down-regulated(simulated-data)]\mbox{}


28801 15752 7608 16432 517 10097 2507 17206 15172 29142 27774 18990 
16535 10805 4087 58 22876 15101 24370 4012 11427 5084 9600 16894 19805 4293 2458 22870 2441 21254 
13253 19695 4591 10390 21017 8 29857 5596 8581 29865 4353 28352 7098 13369 18225 19201 26225 4704 
16647 9525 11714 508 29554 22186 20384 14925 11903 16565 6431 16843 136 22527 26046 26658 5968 11786 
12565 25775 20171 13040 51 17680 2400 29937 10144 23910 4889 20 23295 11705 26495 7247 11397 413 
14288 24522 6555 14376 3638 17392 20009 19615 14040 2308 5349 2565 12827 4764 24670 23303 7087 20765 
5196 29462 26289 26060 4019 29914 25948 20222 12197 21712 2686 977 14266 11573 7349 24956 25457 10579 
6568 28782 23193 23514 4880 15851 330 7595 27658 28029 5795 19654 19772 3665 29135 25879 10659 7438 
4587 29720 2763 25496 6017 25347 8356 22638 3692 8848 13179 12285 9603 28607 13295 11050 23022 21323 
17671 7894 7580 14430 18362 28794 10172 22286 25320 25651 25590 27536 9187 1584 18084 17802 15579 
1318 2006 18239 20876 13047 23182 13250 3003 18035 5206 28606 15141 14262 29614 23432 5279 23404 6239 
28438 21020 8630 2041 4933 5699 28448 2801 27316 9329 20022 5650 13377 7212 22980 2791 11173 20636 
26499 7373 3699 24165 16755 5952 14970 28729 8510 7146 8324 1976 27210 11198 11685 29773 17209 29220 
14494 11037 2514 12886 14303 3628 5961 10876 25 24479 18502 24773 21684 21947 19723 1642 4555 12036 
4622 11535 23197 25036 17138 12043 20596 13776 7220 7152 11463 4757 16767 6858 14847 22776 19439 3988 
3918 12832 289 16218 15470 12010 29466 2979 14977 1046 5864 29896 10048 22492 18143 26571 21994 20032 
12562 8396 2949 12371 11205 10140 21521 600 4998 25138 3817 8651 16957 26404 26747 1225 9021 4521 
10312 25168 20325 5381 12297 2312 5074 5305 11400 13634 3389 19753 3110 18140 15957 21430 5236 20002 
13083 10765 28374 28307 20262 8591 22046 15658 14930 1411 22251 559 25435 6213 20299 8912 15722 23493 
11266 26811 12165 28659 25876 17807 27004 27873 12888 20309 7999 8118 24990 3268 19570 19602 7134 
11712 15082 6077 13652 4284 28262 29766 29165 11630 22473 19304 22107 124 17473 25271 13082 22827 653 
27732 16449 21830 11321 25951 6694 22939 16348 4169 12286 11428 28194 1040 6753 27715 23683 8564 
20880 29661 19024 5487 20770 6540 24118 12797 15324 19848 5334 26925 18468 6943 28950 27384 24895 
6280 27813 21009 18246 13498 7294 4964 5114 19657 8343 10660 791 9984 20508 3231 3646 18376 24197 
15869 22055 14117 4476 29019 25633 109 6512 17066 6939 6437 24332 16945 7596 10585 
24402 28891 7273 29256 24135 11097 12214 12463 5805 5330 15377 16457 7464 22579 3264 8497 23226 9043 
5568 7662 8167 14474 4525 13346 15580 28848 14495 19355 11876 9715 15009 790 29146 28822 10240 5474 
2997 4643 17627 6570 14796 7832 23401 29769 2348 19953 16344 3319 8326 5665 4417 22595 22804 13716 
19331 6549 24515 15060 14807 26463 9011 11106 25947 12383 4421 24571 15261 22372 9704 3878 11886 
20355 6189 12806 26413 25412 23778 12080 10944 19591 20730 28774 9424 8712 10396 3102 22026 20349 
13859 25864 5891 11629 29538 15218 15567 18012 4013 11941 29227 23332 20187 4251 2649 12755 20729 
9829 13625 7605 2437 6498 22485 4972 10785 20630 13886 19887 15153 23611 1780 7048 22479 25096 29492 
27853 4991 25842 24478 23531 12440 3385 11419 19732 24394 17549 555 25589 6949 6463 1788 29789 21721 
19613 23329 16906 17218 15903 1997 6650 16502 22337 18361 17762 28228 9839 24652 5454 10067 12754 
3380 11926 29233 1097 1641 22119 13562 2347 15729 4428 5045 14877 1672 21121 20875 362 6152 705 28166 
18 599 95 21673 5248 5791 25769 12278 27498 14261 23673 19990 22061 24804 9825 11481 8967 23267 8061 
21614 20589 15883 25944 13128 9209 29965 23039 8585 4927 22956 27542 21291 20272 27769 25543 28291 
21408 9417 27141 4331 23933 6685 4792 27349 12979 3634 27755 11586 15510 24025 19859 10148 26963 
25450 21952 20928 28681 938 2839 27261 27429 17230 

\item[Down-regulated(simulated-data)]\mbox{}

 1290 19359 7024 13458 29054 3126 17261 10987 29308 11893 21108 10098 
12538 13819 29604 28247 26271 20549 18587 1163 26429 1702 1060 7446 26948 2420 17093 17449 9163 18482 
1774 28316 13208 7803 5684 6243 27652 13184 28530 13920 3892 20737 28934 22475 17344 27413 13075 
19865 4384 16810 12104 16381 861 23334 11223 12324 16630 2592 5428 12088 14508 22728 26779 10476 
15215 4761 5261 12113 14148 9100 14655 4580 2767 23836 26500 8385 9982 11007 18331 23912 27150 18400 
28124 20804 15840 21630 10222 27319 13911 19830 7522 22907 1130 17387 25989 10952 21821 14840 11143 
16198 18249 16605 24046 13632 22860 1844 15283 26710 11324 12407 2524 5806 2205 21277 177 7969 23189 
2078 29438 11835 1576 24695 23027 8925 11136 21321 8060 12694 12413 7162 1436 2528 6021 1677 20776 
23789 14487 15179 24662 14826 17775 21247 12110 1499 27209 18187 20195 24715 12404 20683 21968 19561 
20846 20101 26005 11278 27897 1107 16655 3499 9128 724 7301 27374 16177 3300 16900 22128 16360 23204 
4427 8112 6309 5322 8861 20070 19147 26079 8210 10727 10661 1793 12226 23635 4477 13409 19525 13400 
6078 10768 24862 21443 27865 8598 27502 21812 24418 23692 969 13596 8338 1501 658 19992 24833 13035 
2891 8532 6063 15522 16259 9017 6850 5046 9809 8640 24174 19168 19459 8539 3587 28995 17168 8817 
28038 832 13777 2804 12264 28832 19060 102 1831 16700 20434 29333 5036 21825 7752 21885 26190 22899 
12989 14058 25329 25815 26952 26249 17125 25172 10260 8399 19448 8127 3087 7775 442 8786 16529 25015 
11107 16691 26600 11664 26656 2835 9902 12017 5642 26833 29636 17847 26493 8185 19070 19541 7495 
25786 8248 10925 24857 16833 17420 7122 17958 28556 9582 26167 2050 6062 12361 15451 11645 6999 12213 
18377 25241 2779 23686 4281 20657 21109 11347 18309 28281 761 8965 738 22016 17400 24908 13605 17514 
20836 4634 4497 21029 19384 29854 5779 24613 20422 25003 27368 7078 5243 9605 14393 4725 28491 12588 
23649 16977 4108 3591 11696 16508 23562 3142 7455 10595 29372 18978 20265 6876 20985 10711 28551 
12678 4432 2717 10692 7197 26767 5697 4367 29230 7655 6696 8706 11189 19261 15090 7512 25729 23442 
21883 14470 6857 14268 22904 25366 17152 29484 6907 20957 4679 21554 26128 23837 26987 27997 14284 
7243 9291 27805 6115 26634 2031 2272 5574 15715 17867 2097 12861 18381 24802 23663 15974 12026 17352 
28472 10429 27515 10372 28033 28929 19365 1205 27149 2403 10091 283 16109 7040 2498 7480 17464 18075 
12221 799 10588 11585 13365 24511 12705 27007 18031 12215 24059 4338 3037 7161 6002 12586 25527 19042 
12959 23845 21099 20643 4612 7107 18687 3762 6814 8086 21820 11288 11230 14476 6505 3697 8092 24905 
18215 13286 20650 22213 13373 27938 13435 9837 13847 25361 7003 20609 9749 24073 27565 3454 
13577 20673 29765 11275 29243 12075 8790 16538 
\end{description}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with another table package (xtabular for example), and for that type of table, i will try to insert a table into another table

Comment: I suppose you mean ` xltabular`?

Comment: what do you mean to insert a table into another table??

Answer (score 0):

The extra line at the top is given maybe by the `\hline` at the beginning of the table.

For what I understood, maybe you may have a look at `\multirow` and `\multicolum` commands in the `multirow` package: see [here](https://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/) for an explanation.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question: where would use of `\multicolumn` help in this layout?

Comment: @David, I understood that ALI wanted a table in which the first column has many rows, while the second column has only one row, then I suggest to use `\multirow`. Nonetheless, since I did not fully understood what ALI desires, I included also the `\multicolumn` option because maybe it reveals useful for some purposes.

Comment: The supplied code in the question (which you could use in your answer)  only has two rows, if you use `\multirow` then there can be no breaking at all as that will be the whole table.

Comment: What I understood from ALI question ("i try to create a long table that has multiple rows in one column, and in another column, i have one row") is that he wanted a table with 2 columns, in which the first one has n rows and the second only one. My natural idea is using /multirow, even if this is not the layout I would give to a table.